# Dataflow --requirements_file behavior -- will it always stage deps to GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've noticed that when I pass in a `pip` requirements file to the `--requirements_file` argument, my local environment downloads these requirements, and stages tarballs to GCS.  Then the Dataflow workers pick up these dependencies, without any need to egress to pypi.org.  This is pretty neat, since my workers can get their dependencies without public IPs.

My question is whether this is expected, "official" behavior -- or an implementation detail subject to change?

I've come across code documentation that seems to read that the workers themselves would need internet access to pypi.org, which is not what I'm actually observing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0df7a8ea5dbc4f084e4b3b571f87253d180c07df/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L553) of the `GoogleCloudOptions` class there is this option `--staging_location` that is the GCS path for staging code packages needed by workers (e.g. gs://bucket/object), see option details [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0df7a8ea5dbc4f084e4b3b571f87253d180c07df/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L579). Which tell us that our staging location is in GCS.

Now following the option `--requirements_file` on the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0df7a8ea5dbc4f084e4b3b571f87253d180c07df/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L940), I could find the following:

> If used, all the packages specified will be downloaded, cached (use
> `--requirements_cache` to change default location), and then staged so that they can be automatically installed in workers during startup.
> The cache is refreshed as needed avoiding extra downloads for existing
> packages. Typically the file is named requirements.txt.

Additionally, it seems that GCS is always used as storage for all the jobs resources, (which seems to include the PyPI packages). This is because the workers can be started and stopped anytime, and it's required a permanent location to put all the code and libraries that workers need. The staging location is that place, and as this is in GCS, we can conclude that yes, PyPI packages are first cached and later staged on the GCS stage location.

With this,you can rest assure that if the required versions of the PyPI packages are in the `staging_location`, the workers won't need internet access to pypi.org in order to install the required packages specified on the `requirements.txt` file.

For more details on how the stage of job resources is done you can take a look at the the `create_and_stage_job_resources` function definition [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0df7a8ea5dbc4f084e4b3b571f87253d180c07df/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/stager.py#L321). For a quick summary reference, we can see what's returned:

```
    Returns:
      A tuple of:
      1) retrieval token
      2) A list of file names (no paths) for the resources staged. All the
      files are assumed to be staged at staging_location
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that it is not jus the _requirements.txt_ file which is staged, but the packages themselves (as tarballs) get staged in GCS too!  The documentation doesn't seem to mention this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I made a rework on the answer to be more specific, trying to give you a more clear answer. I hope it helps you, if you think that there is room for improvement and make it more clear, let me know.

Comment: Hi Thomas, regarding the functionality of using GCS as `staging_location` possibly being modified in a near future. I could say what it's very unlikely to happen, as most of the GCP services that require a stating location to move data/files use GCS. So you could think of it as being a common/best practice. Nonetheless, in this case if you would like to have a more official statement, you could reach the Apache Beam team using their JIRA [page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues), so they can let you know if they have planned any change like this on their road-map.